# Using up bandwidth when calling readfile() on a different server?

Tags: php, bandwidth, readfile

I have a question about how servers communicate with each other and how it takes up bandwidth.  I'll use an example to better explain my question.

I have two sites: www.jojoedad.com and resources.jojoedad.com.  Each site resides on a separate server (with different IPs and on different machines).  "www| is used mainly for handling front-end tasks such as serving up different web pages.  "resources" stores a whole bunch of video files and is meant to only serve up large video files.

Assume that I code it correctly so only "www" can be accessed by the public and "resources" can only be accessed by calling scripts on "www".  Will large bandwidths of "www" be taken up if users retrieve videos on "resources" through www.jojoedad.com like this:

```
http://www.jojoedad.com/getVideo.php?filename=myVideo.mp4
```

and in getVideo.php, I have something like this:

```
header("Content-Type..."); // I didn't fill in details for this line
header("Content-disposition..."); // I didn't fill in details for this line
header("COntent-description..."); // I didn't fill in details for this line
readfile("http://resources.jojoedad.com/video_files/{$_GET['filename']}");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should loko into creating a Proxy on your www machine. mod_proxy, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass if you're on apache. And yes your www-machine will use as much bandwidth to the outside as if it was hosting it itself. That is also the case with a proxy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because as the process is now, you're doing this:

1. www connects to resources
2. www downloads video from resources
3. www streams video to user

Meaning you're doubling your work. The script that puts out the video files should be on `resources.joedad.com` and use your header calls plus `readfile` using the path to the video file. An example would be:

```
readfile('/home/user/videos/myVideo.mp4)
```

so it doesn't have to make a connection to itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, so this means that I cannot hide "resources" from the user then?  My thinking is that to execute the script you mentioned on "resources", I have to somehow get "www" to redirect the user to "resources" without using readfile on "www".  Am I correct?  Thanks again @onteria_.

Comment: While `resources` would still be visible, you can still implement session based control. This will require a modification of your php.ini file http://www.markdeepwell.com/2010/03/php-session-sharing-among-subdomains/ There might be an option with `mod_rewrite`, but that would require a bit more research.

Answer (score 2):

The fun thing is this will use *twice* the bandwidth on `www` -- once to retrieve the file from `resources` and once to send the data to the client -- and once on `resources`. Many data centers charge less (or nothing) for internal data traffic, so it might not be a big deal.

If you like restricting access to `resources` to come from `www` and only from `www`, then it might even be worth the triple-bandwidth costs to get a file *from* `resources` to `www` and then again from `www` to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will use the bandwidth needed by the video once on resources and once again on www